# Connection error when loading the app (using Parse.com)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com SDK.
my internet connection is OK and reset the emulator not help.
And for some reason, from yesterday i see this message every time the app load:

```
2014-11-25 10:00:32.275 myApp[6551:952636] Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo=0x78f3b6f0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.parse.com/2/client_events, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=57, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/2/client_events, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, NSUnderlyingError=0x78f3ad40 "The network connection was lost."} (Code: 100, Version: 1.4.0)
2014-11-25 10:00:32.275 myApp[6551:952637] Attempt at runEventually command timed out. Waiting 600.000000 seconds. 5 retries remaining.
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to first subscribe parse status mail list from [here](http://status.parse.com/).

Check your api number.

Reset simulator and close open xcode.

If you reset simulator, problem could be from api keys or parse.